# Want to clarify my understanding on R-type instruction

Tags: riscv

I am now working on a simple risc-v processor which will be compatible with the following cmds:
[image]

If I don't understand wrongly, is it correct that all the instructions ***apart from the highlighted*** are in R-type? Since I am constructing a logical circuit to distinguish the two groups (R-type / non R-type). Many thanks!

Comment: R-Types have 3 registers, so any instruction that doesn't have `rs1`, `rs2`, and `rd` isn't an R-Type, eh?  Like `slli`, `lw` and `sw` for example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RISC-V [specs](https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/riscv-spec.pdf) say at page 22:

> All branch instructions use the B-type instruction format.

So `BEQ`, `BNE` etc are not R, but B. `SLLI` is I type. The only R types here are `ADD` and `SUB`. If you really try to implement a RISC-V cpu, then it would be wise to get familiar with this documentation.